# How to remove a blank row from slicer?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, slicers

I have a slicer which is used to manipulate a PivotTable.  The PivotTable is a list of filters.  Ultimately, the slicers + PivotTable are used to retrieve data and populate a worksheet for end users.

### Issue

I recently added a combobox that autocompletes data so end users could quickly type what they were looking for rather than spend the time scrolling through each slicer and selecting appropriate options.  As I have been testing the sheet, I noticed a blank row has appeared at the top of one of my slicers.  How do I remove this blank row?

### Attempts

I checked the data source for the PivotTable + slicers, there are no blank rows.  I did a GoTo --> Blanks to try and isolate any blank cells (no blank cells in the data).  I refreshed the data source and I also changed the data source to what it should be, the blank row in the slicer is still there, despite no blanks in my PivotTable data.  I also went to Slicer Settings and checked 'Hide items with no data' but still, the blank entry in the slicer persists.

I would add that vba code that manipulates the PivotTable isn't modifying the slicers in any way.  In my vba I call:

When I lock the sheet:

`Me.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True`

In the `ComboBox1_Click()` event after the user selects an entry from the autocomplete dropdown:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Portfolio").CurrentPage = _
                ComboBox1.Value
```

And when a user clicks a 'Clear Filters' button I call:

`ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").ClearAllFilters`

Those are the only manipulations of the PivotTable within my vba code.

Comment: I'll happily take a look if you post a sample file.

Comment: I can attempt to, but it is a rather confidential file and I would need to consider a way to effectively anonymize the data but maintain my issue.  I'm wondering if I somehow corrupted something and I just need to start with the old version and re-apply all of my changes.